# WAMP 2.2 mysqli_connect can't find localhost

Tags: php, mysql, windows, mysqli, wamp

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in E:\www\auth\includes\class.db.php on line 16
```

Here's the error i get when i try to use mysqli_connect on wamp 2.2.

php extension php_mysqli is activated. localhost works fine, phpmyadmin works fine, mysql console works fine. my hosts file looks perfectly normal.

I've tried:
    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_HOST", "localhost:3306");
    define("DB_HOST", "localhost:80");

I've checked my.ini and it is set to listen to the default port.

What could i be overlooking? I'm unfamiliar with running mysql/php on windows so i'm probably missing something obvious, but this is really doing my head in.

only thing i did was change my document_root to E:/www/forum in httpd.conf
and i'm trying to include my class.db which is located at e:/www/auth
but i don't see this causing issues. Tried with a diff user then root also, no luck.

Thank you for your time :)

only part i modified in httpd.conf

```
ServerName localhost:80

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "e:/www/forum/"

<Directory "e:/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>
```

Comment: Can you connect to your MySQL instance using a client like [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html)?

Comment: @tadman i will try that asap and get back to you. haven't installed one yet.

Comment: Can we see the line where you make the connection? mysqli_connect(DB_HOST...) - without sensitive data, obviously.